# How can close an open 'Panel' in 'Collapse' with a separate button in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I open the first 'Panel' in 'Collapse'. I click the button -> the first 'Panel' closes. I open the second 'Panel'. I click the button -> close the second 'Panel'.

I'm using the 'Panel' component from the `ant` design library.

I try to do it this way: I click button, the flag changes and adds the `close {display: none}` class. I have a problem with class overwriting.

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1xxrkc

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import Hello from './Hello';
    import './style.css';
    import { Collapse } from 'antd';

    const { Panel } = Collapse;
    class App extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          close: false
        };
      }

      callback = (key) => {
        console.log(key);
      }

      onClose = () => {
        close: true;
      }


      render() {


    const text = (
      <p style={{ paddingLeft: 24 }}>
        A dog is a type of domesticated animal. Known for its loyalty and faithfulness, it can be found
        as a welcome guest in many households across the world.
      </p>
    );
        return (
          <div>
            <Collapse defaultActiveKey={['1']} onChange={this.callback}>
              <Panel className={this.state.close ? "close" : null } 
 header="This is panel header with arrow icon" key="1">
                <p>{text}</p>
              </Panel>
              <Panel className={this.state.close ? "close" : null } 
 showArrow={false} header="This is panel header with no arrow icon" key="2">
                <p>{text}</p>
              </Panel>
            </Collapse>

          <button className="button" onClick={this.onClose}>Close</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: What is the use of  `close` button at the buttom

Comment: I don't understand what are you looking for exactly, can you please elaborate your problem a little more.

Comment: @Annaimahalingam When Panel is open. I want to use button to close Panel.

Comment: @MonikaMangal When Panel is open. I want to use button to close Panel.

Comment: Both panels should close when you click the close button or Open panel should close I'm right?

Comment: @Annaimahalingam When I have open two panels should close two panels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`antd-Collapse` library is appending the `ant-collapse-content-active` and `ant-collapse-content-inactive` Class when `Collapse`

You Just need to add this **css**  `.ant-collapse-content-inactive{ display: none;}` in `style.css` file.

```css
.ant-collapse-content-inactive{
  display: none;
}
.ant-collapse-content-active{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import { Collapse } from 'antd';

const { Panel } = Collapse;

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();   
  }

  callback = (key) => {
    
  }

  onClose = () => {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".ant-collapse-item-active");    
    if(x.length){
      for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) { 
        setTimeout(function () {
        var el = document.querySelector(".ant-collapse-item-active");        
        el.children[0].click();  
    }, 100);          
    }
  }
    
}    
  


  render() {
const text = (
  <p style={{ paddingLeft: 24 }}>
    A dog is a type of domesticated animal. Known for its loyalty and faithfulness, it can be found
    as a welcome guest in many households across the world.
  </p>
);
    return (
      <div>
        <Collapse defaultActiveKey={['1']} onChange={this.callback}>
          <Panel  header="This is panel header with arrow icon" key="1">
            <p>{text}</p>
          </Panel>
          <Panel   showArrow={false} header="This is panel header with no arrow icon" key="2">
            <p>{text}</p>
          </Panel>
        </Collapse>

      <button className="button" onClick={this.onClose}>Close</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Close button does not work, collapse only will work, I'm looking for the solution, the close is adding on page load, if we add dynamically is not appending the close class

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Change the `this.state` to `onClose = () => {    this.setState({close:true })
  }`

and add the css in style.css
`.close .ant-collapse-content-active{
  display :none;
}
`

Comment: But there is one problem. If you close the panels. Try to open it again. You must click twice on panel